# Prerequisites for 'Fibre Bundles' by 'Dale Husemoller'

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I wish to study the book 'Fibre Bundles' by Dale Husemoller. How much Algebraic Topology is required for studying this book ? Would a knowledge of fundamental groups, covering spaces (say from second part of 'Topology' by Munkres)  and Singular Homology (say 1st Chapter of 'Homology Theory' by J.Vick) suffice ? Please suggest other references for the prerequisites as well.

Comment: Yes, I think you should be fine. The first 4-5 chapters are pretty self-contained, if my memory serves me right.

Comment: At some point knowing the basics of cohomology would be helpful, but you don't need to know it immediately.